# Error processing package libssl1.1:amd64

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dpkg

When trying to install or update packages, I got the following error:

> dpkg: error processing package libssl1.1:amd64 (--configure):
>
> installed libssl1.1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess
>   returned error exit status 10
>
> Errors occurred while processing the following packets: 
>   libssl1.1:amd64
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
>   returned an error code (1)

I did:

> sudo dpkg --configure -a
>
> sudo apt-get install -f

Do I need reinstall dpkg?

Answer (score 5):

I was stucked in the same problem. I tried this and worked to me:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo rm libssl1.1:amd64.postinst libssl1.1:amd64.shlibs libssl1.1:amd64.postrm
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

got from [linuxquestions.org forum](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/libssl1-1-amd64-crash-4175655773-print/).

Comment: This helped, thank you very much.

Comment: Hey it worked !! Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat` it will rebuild the .dat files when you run apt-get again.
[credit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925232/error-with-libpam-systemdamd64-dpkg-error)